# Generic way of lazily evaluating (short-circuiting) with std::conditional_t

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, type-traits

While playing around with compile-time string (variadic lists of `char`) manipulation, I needed to implement a way of checking if a compile-time string contained another (smaller) compile-time string.
This was my first attempt:

```cpp
template<int I1, int I2, typename, typename> struct Contains;

template<int I1, int I2, char... Cs1, char... Cs2> 
struct Contains<I1, I2, CharList<Cs1...>, CharList<Cs2...>>
{
    using L1 = CharList<Cs1...>;
    using L2 = CharList<Cs2...>;

    using Type = std::conditional_t
    <
        (I1 >= sizeof...(Cs1)),
        std::false_type,
        std::conditional
        <
            (L1::template at<I1>() != L2::template at<I2>()),
            typename Contains<I1 + 1, 0, L1, L2>::Type,
            std::conditional
            <
                (I2 == sizeof...(Cs2) - 1),
                std::true_type,
                typename Contains<I1 + 1, I2 + 1, L1, L2>::Type
            >
        >
    >;
};
```

I find this solution extremely easy to read and reason about. Unfortunately, **it doesn't work**.

The compiler always tries to instantiate every single branch of `std::conditional`, even those which are not taken. To put it in another way, **short-circuiting** isn't happening.
This causes `Contains` to be instantiated infinitely.

I've solved my original problem by separating every `std::conditional` block in a separate template class where the condition results are handled as partial specializations.
It works, but unfortunately I find it very hard to read/modify.

---

**Is there a way to lazily instantiate a template type and be close to my original solution?**

I was thinking that I could wrap the greedily instantiated templates in a type like:

```cpp
DeferInstantiation<typename Contains<I1 + 1, 0, L1, L2>::Type>
```

This should prevent greedy instantiations of the template argument.
Is it somehow possible to implement `DeferInstantiation<T>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a generic template to allow deferred instantiation by simply not instantiating :)

```
template <bool B, template <typename...> class TrueTemplate, template <typename...> class FalseTemplate, typename ArgsTuple>
struct LazyConditional;

template <template <typename...> class TrueTemplate, template <typename...> class FalseTemplate, typename ... Args>
struct LazyConditional<true, TrueTemplate, FalseTemplate, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
  using type = TrueTemplate<Args...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class TrueTemplate, template <typename...> class FalseTemplate, typename ... Args>
struct LazyConditional<false, TrueTemplate, FalseTemplate, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
  using type = FalseTemplate<Args...>;
};
```

For completeness, a simple example demonstrating its use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct OneParam
{
  void foo(){std::cout << "OneParam" << std::endl;}
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct TwoParam
{
  void foo(){std::cout << "TwoParam" << std::endl;}
};

template <bool B, template <typename...> class TrueTemplate, template <typename...> class FalseTemplate, typename ArgsTuple>
struct LazyConditional;

template <template <typename...> class TrueTemplate, template <typename...> class FalseTemplate, typename ... Args>
struct LazyConditional<true, TrueTemplate, FalseTemplate, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
  using type = TrueTemplate<Args...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class TrueTemplate, template <typename...> class FalseTemplate, typename ... Args>
struct LazyConditional<false, TrueTemplate, FalseTemplate, std::tuple<Args...>>
{
  using type = FalseTemplate<Args...>;
};

template <typename ... Args>
struct OneOrTwoParam
{
  using type = typename LazyConditional<sizeof...(Args)==1, OneParam, TwoParam, std::tuple<Args...> >::type;
};

int main()
{
  OneOrTwoParam<int>::type().foo();
  OneOrTwoParam<int, int>::type().foo();
  return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
OneParam
TwoParam
```

Answer (score 7):

> The compiler always tries to instantiate every single branch of std::conditional, even those which are not taken. 
>   To put it in another way, short-circuiting isn't happening.

`std::conditional<B,T,F>` is provided for the purpose of executing a compiletime
choice between given *types* `T` and `F`, depending on the boolean `B`. The
choice is effected by specialization. When `B` is true, the instantiated specialization is:

```
std::conditional<true,T,F>
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

And when `B` is false, the the instantiated specialization is:

```
std::conditional<false,T,F>
{
    typedef F type;
};
```

Note that to instantiate *either* specialization, both `T` and `F` must
be instantiated. *There are no "branches"*. The notion of "short-circuiting" the
instantiation of either `std::conditional<true,T,F>` or `std::conditional<false,T,F>`
could only mean *not doing it*.

So no, it is not possible to implement `DeferInstantiation<U>`, for type parameter
`U`, such that an instantiation of

```
std::conditional<{true|false},DeferInstantiation<T>,DeferInstantiation<F>>
```

will not entail instantiation of `DeferInstantiation<T>` and `DeferInstantiation<F>>`,
and therefore of `T`, and of `F`.

For executing a compiletime choice as to which or two or more *templates* shall be
instantiated, the language provides *specialization* (as just illustrated
by the definition of `std::conditional<B,T,F>` itself); it provides *function template overload
resolution*, and it provides [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).
Specialization and overload resolution can each be synergetically leveraged with
SFINAE, via the library support of [`std::enable_if<B,T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

The problem that has obstructed you in crafting the particular recursive meta-function
that you want is not one of choosing between given *types* but of choosing the *template*
into which recursive instantiation shall be directed.`std::conditional` is not
to the purpose. @Pradhan's answer demonstrates that a template different from `std::conditional`
can well be written to effect a compiletime choice between two *templates*, without
entailing that both of them shall be instantiated. He applies specialization to do it.

As you say, you have already figured out a specialization solution to the
problem. This is in principle the right way to recursively control
template selection in recursive meta-functions. However, with the advent of 
`constexpr`, recursive meta-functions do not command anything like the market share of
problems that they formerly did, and most of the brain-ache they occasioned
is a thing of the past.

The particular problem here - determining at compiletime whether one string is a substring
of another - can be solved without grappling with template meta-programming, and without 
representing compiletime strings otherwise than as traditional string literals:

```
#include <cstddef>

constexpr std::size_t str_len(char const *s)
{
    return *s ? 1 + str_len(s + 1) : 0;
}

constexpr bool 
is_substr(char const * src, char const *targ, 
            std::size_t si = 0, std::size_t ti = 0)
{
    return  !targ[ti] ? true :
                str_len(src + si) < str_len(targ + ti) ? false :
                    src[si] == targ[ti] ? 
                        is_substr(src,targ,si + 1, ti + 1) :
                            is_substr(src,targ,si + 1, 0);
}

// Compiletime tests...

static_assert(is_substr("",""),"");
static_assert(is_substr("qwerty",""),"");
static_assert(is_substr("qwerty","qwerty"),"");
static_assert(is_substr("qwerty","qwert"),"");
static_assert(is_substr("qwerty","werty"),"");
static_assert(is_substr("qwerty","wert"),"");
static_assert(is_substr("qwerty","er"),"");
static_assert(!is_substr("qwerty","qy"),"");
static_assert(!is_substr("qwerty","et"),"");
static_assert(!is_substr("qwerty","qwertyz"),"");
static_assert(!is_substr("qwerty","pqwerty"),"");
static_assert(!is_substr("","qwerty"),"");

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This will compile as C++11 or better.

You may well have reasons for wishing to represent compiletime strings
as `CharList<char ...>` other than thus rendering them amenable to
TMP compiletime queries such as this. We can see that `CharList<char ...Cs>`
has a static constant `size` member evaluating to `sizeof...(Cs)` and has
a static `at<N>()` member function evaluating to the `N`th of the `...Cs`.
In that case (assuming that `at<N>()` is debugged), you might adapt
`is_substr` to be a template function expecting `CharList<char ...>`
parameters on roughly the following lines:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<
    class SrcList, class TargList, std::size_t SrcI = 0, std::size_t TargI = 0>
constexpr typename 
std::enable_if<(TargI == TargList::size && SrcI <= SrcList::size),bool>::type 
is_substr()
{
    return true;
}

template<
    class SrcList, class TargList, std::size_t SrcI = 0, std::size_t TargI = 0>
constexpr typename 
std::enable_if<(TargI < TargList::size && SrcI == SrcList::size),bool>::type 
is_substr()
{
    return false;
}

template<
    class SrcList, class TargList, std::size_t SrcI = 0, std::size_t TargI = 0>
constexpr typename 
std::enable_if<(TargI < TargList::size && SrcI < SrcList::size),bool>::type 
is_substr()
{
    return  SrcList::template at<SrcI>() == TargList::template at<TargI>() ? 
                is_substr<SrcList,TargList,SrcI + 1,TargI + 1>() :
                is_substr<SrcList,TargList,SrcI + 1,0>();
}
```

which illustrates the application of SFINAE, leveraged by `std::enable_if`

Finally, you could also be interested in this program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<char const * Arr>
struct string_lit_type 
{
    static constexpr const char * str = Arr;
    static constexpr std::size_t size = str_len(str);
    static constexpr char at(std::size_t i) {
        return str[i];
    }
};

constexpr char arr[] = "Hello World\n";

int main()
{
    std::cout << string_lit_type<arr>::str;
    std::cout << string_lit_type<arr>::size << std::endl;
    std::cout << string_lit_type<arr>::at(0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which prints:

```
Hello World
12
H
```

(Code compiled with g++ 4.9, clang 3.5)

Answer (score 1):

`DeferInstantiation` is the wrong approach; there are much simpler ways.

The solution to short-circuiting in `std::conditional_t` is very simple, especially if you have two traits (i.e. types with a `::type` alias) already.
Instead of writing:

```cpp
std::conditional_t<condition, typename A::type, typename B::type>
```

... write:

```cpp
typename std::conditional_t<condition, A, B>::type
```

Even if `A::type` is not a valid type, the trait `A` in itself is. It will not be instantiated unless you access `::type`, which enables the lazy evaluation you want.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the OP that it is unfortunate to not have short-circuiting in std::conditional (or call it SFINAE in the unentered branch, so that incorrect types do not lead to an error).

I had the same problem in my code and could solve it by using `if constexpr` in a constexpr lambda. So, instead of

```
using type = std::conditional_t<logical, A, B>;
```

use

```
auto get_type = []()
{
    if constexpr(logical)
    {
        return std::declval<A>();
    }
    else
    {
        return std::declval<B>();
    }
};
using type = decltype(get_type());
```

which, however, is by far less readable.

Comment: The lambda needs to be inside `decltype`, otherwise this fails to compile. That would only be possible in C++20 though. And even then, this solution only works when `A` and `B` are copyable or movable. Overall, this is really broken.

Comment: @JanSchultke: you are right, it doesn't work anymore as the static checks in decltype seems to have changed. And yes, for non-copyable, non-moveable types, you'd have to further extend it. [Here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b09709b8903c64e) is a version with the usual decltype definition from std-c++ that works also for non-copyable, non-moveable constraints and is C++17 (you need that for if constexpr). Don't know whether that meets your definition of not-broken, but it's an idea.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that version, yeah.