# What is the evaluation strategy (eager, lazy, ...) of C++ metafunctions such as std::conditional?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, operator-precedence, evaluation-strategy

C++14 draft n4140 reads

> `T` shall be an enumeration type

for `template <class T> struct underlying_type`.

How bad is it to write

```
std::conditional_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::underlying_type_t<T>, foo>
```

when `T` can be an arbitrary type? Will I step onto an UB and will the compiler delete my $HOME (because language lawyers say "anything can happen under an UB") ?

Comment: UB is something that happens at runtime, template functions such as this do their work at compile time. As for "will it delete $HOME" see [Chandler's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG1OZ69H_-o)

Comment: This is compile-time evaluation, not run-time. You won't run into UB here.

Comment: @Borgleader OK "will the resulting binary possibly delete my $HOME" ? Actually I'm not even sure if it constitutes an UB to write `std::underlying_type_t<void>` straight (w/o `std::conditional`.) Does "shall" there mean its violation leads to an ill-formed program?

Comment: @nodakai: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) states it pretty well: "If T is a complete enumeration type, provides a member typedef type that names the underlying type of T.
Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.". Edit: So don't try to use `std::underlying_type_t<void>`

Comment: @AndyG I would not have posted this question if I could 100 % trust a community-driven wiki. I could not easily find any statements in n4140 which supports the last statement in your quote.

Comment: Related: [Generic way of lazily evaluating (short-circuiting) with std::conditional_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28432977/5740428)

Comment: According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type), C++20 has updated `std::underlying_type` so that it's defined not to have `type` unless `T` is an enum so my concern is no longer a problem! (although I'm not sure if I'll come back to writing C++ again)
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/meta.trans.other#lib:underlying_type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Will I step onto an UB [...]

Technically, yes. But practically, it just won't compile for non-enumeration types. When you write:

```
std::conditional_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::underlying_type_t<T>, foo>;    
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That template parameter must be evaluated *before* the `conditional` template can be instantiated. This is equivalent to all function arguments having to be invoked before the body of the function begins. For non-enumerated types, `underlying_type<T>` is incomplete (sure it's specified as undefined in the standard but let's be reasonable), so there is no `underlying_type_t`. So the instantiation fails.

What you need to do is *delay* the instantiation in that case:

```
template <class T> struct tag { using type = T; };

typename std::conditional_t<
    std::is_enum<T>::value,
    std::underlying_type<T>,
    tag<foo>>::type;
```

Now, our `conditional` instead of selecting types is selecting a metafunction! `underlying_type<T>::type` will only be instantiated for `T` being an enum. We additionally have to wrap `foo` to turn it into a metafunction.

This is a common pattern and was a special thing in Boost.MPL called `eval_if`, which would look like:

```
template <bool B, class T, class F>
using eval_if_t = typename std::conditional_t<B, T, F>::type;
```

Note that we're both using `conditional_t` *and* `::type`.

Comment: OK, so C++ metafunctions employ eager evaluation (if we don't use your "tag" trick.) Your post is very educating but I think I need a bit more time to grasp it.

Comment: @nodakai Think of it as - template arguments are to metafunctions what function arguments are to functions.