# In a template function, How do I use std::underlying_type just if type of the input is enum class?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, static-cast, enum-class

I have a piece of code that returns the value of some bits of a given number (I counted enum classes as a number too, using a static_cast).

```
template<typename Type>
bool get_bits(Type input, uint8_t offset, uint8_t n, Type* destination)
{
    if (offset + n> sizeof(Type) * 8)
        return false;

    Type bitmask = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        bitmask |= (1 << i);

    *destination = static_cast<Type>(input >> offset & bitmask);
    return true;
}
```

This function tries to return the value of `n` bits of `input` beginning from the `offset`. It works fine for integral types but when I try to use it with enum classes, compilation fails. I tried to use [std::underlying_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) and then it worked for enum classes but not for integral types :|. How can I use it for both of them? I mean if the type is enum class, I want to cast the input to its `underlying_type`, do some bitwise operations, and then store the result (using `static_cast`) to the destination. But these casts should not be done for integral types that don't have underlying_type.

Comment: Not related to the question: `Type bitmask = (Type{1} << n) - 1;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need it often, it's possible to write an adapter over `std::underlying_type`. Something like this

```
namespace detail {
  template<typename T, bool = std::is_enum<T>::value>
  struct underlying_type { using type = T; };

  template<typename T>
  struct underlying_type<T, true> : ::std::underlying_type<T> {};
}
```

When you use `detail::underlying_type<T>` substitution occurs into the default argument too. When the supplied type is not an enumeration, the primary template matches the arguments (implicitly), and the exposed `type` is `T`.

When the supplied type is an enumeration (and only then), the specialization gets used. And all it does is forward to the standard trait.

Answer (score 4):

You can use SFINAE to split the enum class implementation:

```cpp
template <typename Type,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<Type>>>
bool get_bits(Type input, uint8_t offset, uint8_t n, Type* destination) {
    // enum-class implementation
}
```

and integral implementation:

```cpp
template <typename Type,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Type>>>
bool get_bits(Type input, uint8_t offset, uint8_t n, Type* destination) {
    // integral implementation
}
```

The above is a C++17 version.

For C++11, you would have something like:

```cpp
template <typename Type,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<Type>::value>::type* = nullptr>
bool get_bits(Type input, uint8_t offset, uint8_t n, Type* destination) {
    // enum-class implementation
}

template <typename Type,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Type>::value>::type* = nullptr>
bool get_bits(Type input, uint8_t offset, uint8_t n, Type* destination) {
    // integral implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a shorter, clearer version of the accepted answer. In C++20:

```cpp
using maybe_underlying_type = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_enum_v<Type>,
    std::underlying_type<Type>,
    std::type_identity<Type>>::type;
```

You can use this whenever you need to gracefully apply `std::underlying_type` inside your function.
Note that you cannot use `std::underlying_type_t` because this would fail to compile if there is no underlying type, so you select the type trait with `std::conditional`, and then access the `::type` in the type trait.

See also: [What is the evaluation strategy (eager, lazy, ...) of C++ metafunctions such as std::conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41267824/5740428)

In C++11, you'll have to be a bit more verbose:

```cpp
using maybe_underlying_type = typename std::conditional<
    std::is_enum<Type>::value,
    std::underlying_type<Type>,
    std::enable_if<true, Type>>::type::type;
```