# determine result type of lambdas with different signature

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Suppose I have a routine that receives a callable Lambda as parameter, and this Lambda is allowed to have 2 signatures: it can be called providing an int or 2 ints.

The problem is: how to determine the result type of this Lambda.

The following code illustrates the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class Lambda>
auto f(Lambda&& f)
{
    using result_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_invocable_v<Lambda, int>, std::invoke_result_t<Lambda, int>, std::invoke_result_t<Lambda, int, int>>;
    result_type res;
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Lambda, int>) {
        res = f(3);
    }
    else {
        res =  f(3, 3);
    }
    
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f([](int x) -> int { return x; }) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f([](int x, int y) -> int { return x * y; }) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Check it [Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbddea935ca1b52f).

The code does not compiles because, inside `std::conditional_t`, both the 2nd and 3rd template parameters must be defined, and here clearly only one exists.

I can think about writing a traits that serves to this problem, say exploiting template specialization. Something like

```
template <class F, bool T>
struct helper;

template <class F>
struct helper<F, true> {
    using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, int>;
};

template <class F>
struct helper<F, false> {
    using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, int, int>;
};
```

But before reinventing the wheel: is there a simpler compact solution using the std library? I am interested in a c++17 solution.

Comment: Why try putting this all in one function?  You have two overloads that behave differently so just write two overloads of your function: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5965368bb9ed845

Comment: Also, this is a "known issue" with `std::conditional`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432977/generic-way-of-lazily-evaluating-short-circuiting-with-stdconditional-t

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for your comment. Clearly, the example above is a much simplified one. In a real code, the argument of the Lambda are computed inside f(), then the result is further processed. Inserting an ```if constexpr``` when the Lambda is called, while preserving the rest of the code inside f seems a simple choice in terms of readability of the code...

Comment: sorry, but your code example does not illustrate the problem, because in your code example the solution is trivial. You do not need to spell out `result_type` https://godbolt.org/z/nde4PzMGh

Comment: @francesco If you want to do that then you need to use delayed evaluation like `helper` or the approaches in the linked to Q&A.  Another option is to look into seeing if you can refactor the code where you have an overloads of a function that has the distinct logic in it and then call that overload in your generic function and let overload resolution do the dispatching for you. `auto` as a type and a return type makes this pretty easy to do.

Comment: here is also another way to get the return type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673442/simplest-way-to-determine-return-type-of-function/53673648#53673648

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Surely the code above has a trivial solution. But the question is well posed. Posting a longer, more complex code, would not serve to the question. In a real code, the arguments of the Lambda are determined inside f (in a loop actually), then with a ```if-constexpr``` switch the result is computed, and further processed. It appears a simple solution in terms of the readability of the code to just have a ```if-constexpr``` to decide how to call the Lambda, while retaining the rest of the generic code.

Comment: simple example is fine, but I dont understand why the simple solution would not apply. Anyhow, you got answers already

Comment: actually I am not sure what exactly you mean with "it can be called providing an int or 2 ints". Do you mean one and the same lambda that can be called either via `f(1,1)` or `f(1)` or lambdas that can be called only with 1 and other lambdas than can only be called wtih 2 ints?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Either you provide a Lambda that you can call as ```f(1)``` or (another kind of) a Lambda that you can call as ```f(1,1)```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, you just have to "delay" evaluation:

```
using result_type =
    std::conditional_t<std::is_invocable_v<Lambda, int>,
       std::invoke_result<Lambda, int>,
       std::invoke_result<Lambda, int, int>>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Gr5dGf9e)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this has any benefit over your own type trait. It's just different and it doesn't allow for ambiguity (when both overloads are equally fitting), which may be unwanted:

```cpp
template<class L> auto foo(L&&) -> std::invoke_result_t<L, int>;
template<class L> auto foo(L&&) -> std::invoke_result_t<L, int, int>;

template <class Lambda>
auto f(Lambda&& f) {
    using result_type = decltype(foo(std::forward<Lambda>(f)));
    // ...
}
```

`std::invoke_result::type` - The return type of the Callable type `F` if invoked with the arguments `ArgTypes...`. Only defined if `F` can be called with the arguments `ArgTypes...` in unevaluated context.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n1G39rhjb)

---

Or use what you've already have and initialize `res` directly:

```cpp
template <class Lambda>
auto f(Lambda&& f) {
    decltype(auto) res = [&] {
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Lambda, int>) {
            return f(3);
        } else {
            return f(3, 3);
        }
    }();

    // do other stuff ...

    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j5zrrz1P6)

Answer (score 1):

In your example you do not need `result_type`, but this will do:

```
template <class Lambda>
auto f(Lambda&& f)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Lambda, int>) {
        return f(3);
    }
    else {
        return f(3, 3);
    }
}
```

If you do need `result_type` in your real code, it can be decuded from above `f` via `decltype(f(the_lambda))` or `std::invoke_result_t<f,Lambda>`.